# How to use $regex in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to search my database for Customers that start with FOO or have FOO in their names. For that i took a look at this question -> [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

After that i build my query so that it looks like this ->

```
Customer.find({'name': '/FOO/'}).exec(function (err, customer) {
     console.log(customer);
})
```

but although there is a customer with FOO inside the `'name'` i get no result. If i modify my query to `...({'name': 'FOO'})...` instead of `...({'name': '/FOO/'})...` i get my customer. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should have looked more carefully. The usage is right there within the answers and of course various links to the `$regex` documentation. Also not the "only" question on the subject anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [**`$regex`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) with `$options`

```
Customer.find({'name': { $regex: 'FOO', $options: 'i' }}).exec(function (err, customer) {
     console.log(customer);
})
```

Comment: i was just writing the comment, that it doesn't work, but with your edit, now everything works like a charme - big thanks!