# MoongoDB - find with "LIKE" regex and case sensitive

Tags: regex, mongodb, nosql

I have this:

```
let query = {
  title: {
    $regex: ".*" + req.params.term + ".*"
  }
}
```

Which helps me to find "Tel Aviv" in the collection using the "v" or "viv" or "T" or "A" in the term.

However when I am trying to search for "t" or "a" which are inside the string but are need to be capital - it returns nothing.

How to set a good regex which results with "LIKE" function as I have now but also with aware of capital letters?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet This question is without capital letters. My does.

Comment: If you will see the answers posted in  the duplicate then you might get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to specify options flag for case insensitivity and your modified query should look like this,

```
let query = {
  title: {
    $regex: ".*" + req.params.term + ".*",$options:"$i"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Raz: I think you can simplify the above to `$regex: req.params.term, $options:"$i"`