# MongoDB Search fail on some case

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a schema like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a7acda13b808dbed05d6b7e"),
  name: "An Apple eat by Man"
}
```

For that I wrote the query i.e :

```
db.Collection.find({post: { $regex: req.body.query, $options: "i" }})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

So for that Query if I write "An Apple" it return the data, but if I write "eat man" then it will not return data.

Any guess where I am doing wrong, Any help or suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your regex. Having the regex `/eat man/` will look for strings to contains exactly `"eat man"` and not the separates words themselves.

Example :

```js
console.log(/eat Man/.test('An Apple eat by Man'));
console.log(/eat by Man/.test('An Apple eat by Man'));
console.log(/eat  Man/.test('An Apple eat by Man'));
console.log(/eat by  Man/.test('An Apple eat by Man'));
```

---

You can change your regex to say "Match any string with contains the words 'eat' and 'man'" for example :

```js
console.log(/eat.*Man/.test('An Apple eat by Man'));
```

---

In your case, you can do :

```js
// $regex: req.body.query

const req = {
  body: {
    query: 'Man eat',
  },
};

// Will generate something like (?=.*Man)(?=.*eat)
const regex = req.body.query.split(' ').map(x => `(?=.*${x})`).join('');

console.log((new RegExp(regex, 'i')).test('An apply eat by man'));
```

[image]

Comment: const req = {
  body: {
    query: "Finance Housing"
  }
};

const regex = req.body.query.split(" ").join(".*");

console.log(
  new RegExp(regex, "i").test("Housing Development Finance Corporation")
);

Comment: your answer will fail

Comment: If the words are not in the same order yes you are right

Comment: @Abhay I've changed my answer, so now it works with any order :) Thx for your input

Comment: HOw to allow Questionmark i.e ? on regex which you was suggested