# How to query in Mongo for a String based on expressions

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have lot of Data in Mongo DB, I wanted to query based on a String value and that value contains a url

```
"url" : "http://some-host/api/name/service/list/1234/xyz"
```

I got records count when executed the below query

```
db.mycollection.find({url:"http://some-host/api/name/service/list/1234/xyz"}).count()
```

I want to get all the records which match with

```
some-host/api/name/service/list/
```

I tried using below saamples

```
db.mycollection.find({url:"some-host/api/name/service/list/"}).count()
```

Got zero records

```
db.mycollection.find({url:/.*"some-host/api/name/service/list/".*/}).count()
```

Got error

```
db.mycollection.find({"url":/.*"some-host/api/name/service/list/".*/}).count()
```

Got error

```
db.mycollection.find({"url":/.*some-host/api/name/service/list/.*/}).count()
```

Got Error

```
db.mycollection.find({"url":/.*some-host//api//name//service//list//.*/}).count()
```

Got ...

...

Then no response

Comment: `some\-host\/api\/name\/service\/list` - notice the ``\`` escaping each ``/`` and `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with something like this:

```
db.mycollection.find({'url': {'$regex': 'sometext'}})
```

Please check also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: The question is already doing that. Using `/something/` is the same as `$regex: "something"` Read the manual page yourself to see those examples. But that is not what the question is asking.