# How to perform wildcard searches mongoDB in python with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, wildcard

I have a document such as:

```
{'my_key':  '2019-carbeureter'}
```

I want to search for '*2019*'

```
db.collection.find({'my_key': query_string } # isn't working with the following

query_string = "/2019/"   # doesn't work
query_string = r"/2019/"  # same thing
query_string = ".*2019.*" # doesn't work
```

This other SO question addresses it in native mongoDB, 
but how do I do this in Python using pymongo?
[How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collections.find({'my_key': <str>}) # Isn't going to work as a bare str
```

You need to define an object
add a '$regex' operator/key to the object
the value is then the familiar regex style: `'.*2019.*'`

```
query_string = {'$regex': '.*2019.*'}
results = db.collections.find({'my_key': query_object})
```

or written fully as:

```
results = db.collections.find({'my_key': {'$regex': '.*2019.*'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use '$regex' or another option is to use re module

> import re
>
> pattern  = re.compile('2019')
>
> db.collection.find({'my_key': pattern })