# Mongodb like query with two fields is not working(with php)

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I am writing a `script` to fetch data from two fields but not working. Below is my code

```
$cursor = $collection->find(
    array('$text' => array('$search' => 'रेजिमेंट')),
    array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore'))
);
```

I checked some forum but not helping me.

[How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)
(this is not working and also this have only one field "name" while I required search with two fields.)

Where `$text` is the index set for two fields `title` and `description`.If anyone have idea please share me.

Comment: can you show all your indexes, or atleast your text index. ?Just wanna be sure there is no problem with your indices

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti, indexes are "name" : "description_text_title_text"  .these are working fine with exact match but I am trying to search with match case.

Comment: can you run the same query in your mongodb shell and confirm if its working?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti,I am new in Mongo db ,can you please write query for me as per my requirement?

Comment: you can try : `db.collection_name.find({$text : {$search : 'रेजिमेंट'}})` in your mongo shell, and see if it works in your shell

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti,I got error Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "text index required for $text query (no such collection 'rss_master.collection_name')",
 "code" : 27,
 "codeName" : "IndexNotFound"
}

Comment: it looks like you dont have a text index, thats why it is showing this error.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti,  {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "ms_master.vp_stu_details"
 },
 {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "_fts" : "text",
   "_ftsx" : 1
  },
  "name" : "description_text_title_text",
  "ns" : "ms_master.vp_stu_details",
  "weights" : {
   "description" : 1,
   "title" : 1
  },
  "default_language" : "english",
  "language_override" : "language",
  "textIndexVersion" : 3
 }

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti,but exact search is working fine.As you can check indexes in earlier comments.

Comment: i think you need to add language support in the index as well.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti,how can do this?

Comment: looks like there is no support for hindi language in text search index yet

Comment: did you replace `collection_name` with actual collection name in the query i gave you to run in mongo shell? It looks like, you just copy pasted my code. Please try with  your actual collection name

Comment: oh yes you are correct error is not occured but nothing result..

Comment: since nothing is returned in shell, nothing will come back in your php code as well

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti,so why result is not coming?Please help me.

Comment: i dont think i can properly answer that, it totally depends on your database collection. And it might be also because of the language issue.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti,but exact phrase is working fine .can you please advice how to write like query with two column?

Comment: what two column are you talking about?

Comment: two columns are title and description where from I want to write query and search particular word?