# MongoDb fetch all result if matching some characters in string

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB and writing script in PHP and I am using MongoDB to store information. Currently, I am working on a search result and need a query to fetch result, if some characters are matched then fetch all related data.

currently, I am doing with below script

```
$queryString = ".*".$queryString."*";
$where = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array(
            'title' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
        ),
        array(
            'description' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
        ),
     )
);
```

this is working fine but still some words are skipped. Please let me know what is the best way to get exact information.

e.g:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1360536d94f726ec484426"),
    "master_id" : ObjectId("5d11bab64d51f58dbbd391bf"),
    "title" : "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).",
    "description" : "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "pub_date" : "\n\t   Wed, 26 Jun 2019 13:30:18 GMT\t",
    "created_on" : "2019-06-26 17:38:51",
    "modified_on" : "2019-07-10 09:34:33"
}
```

if we search data with character **"Lor"** then all if any word which have word **"Lor"** is found in collections(e.g Lorem),all result should be return.

this is same as `LIKE` query in `mysql`.

Comment: Please show us example data, a search that works and a search that doesn't work. You should also include all the relevant code, including what the query string contains and how you're actually using the variables you create here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,I have updated the anaswer.I need query  same as like in Mysql.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what your second last sentence mean. As I read it, it sounds like your saying it works?

Comment: It will be good before downvoting any question to tell the exact reason, as I told I am new in Mongo so maybe something is a mistake in my question.:(

Comment: The down votes are most likely not because you don't know Mongo. It's more likely to be because you still haven't included all the information we asked for (and is needed for us to be able to reproduce the issue, which we also don't have a practical example of).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,I mean if search with string "LOR" then all related to this word like should be return after query same as in Mysql. I need same as per link   https://stackoverflow.com/a/3305687/3551147    but this is not working for me

Comment: In your query, try changing `".*".$queryString."*"` to `".*".$queryString.".*"` (there's now a dot before the second `*` as well, just like in the answer you linked to).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,still query is missing some data after applying updated code as per your suggestion. result count return 173 but it should be ~277

Comment: you can use find() method with mongoose model and use slash like /Lor/ for search.

Comment: Well, without a proper [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't really reproduce or test anything so... I'm out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go with case insensitive regex search

Try this :

```
$queryString = ".*".$queryString.".*";
$where = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array(
            'title' => array (
                '$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                '$options' => 'i'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'description' => array (
                '$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                '$options' => 'i'
            )
        ),
     )
);
```

Comment: ,this gives same result,actually I have data in Hindi language so option 'i' will return the same result.May be I need add some more regular expression for better result.

Comment: maybe you are not getting the results because of the language constraints

Comment: yes,it may be cause.thanks for helping me.Can you please help me another question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56983900/3551147  ?