# MongoDb Join query with PHP

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I have two documents and want to join both bocuments and after I want to fetch the data from merged table.

e.g below is the **master** document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d11bab64d51f58dbbd391lm"),
    "title" : "Test test",
    "test_url" : "https://www.example.com/",

}
```

and this one is **detail** document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1360536d94f726ec484426"),
    "master_id" : ObjectId("5d11bab64d51f58dbbd391lm"),
    "title" : "जेल में असलहा लहाराते हुए बदमाशों का वीडियो वायरल, गृह विभाग ने दी सफाई",
    "description" : "जिला कारागार में अपराधियों द्वारा असलहा लहराते हुए वीडियो सामने आया है।िला कारागार में अपराधियों द्वारा असलहा लहराते हुए वीडियो सामने आया है।िला कारागार में अपराधियों द्वारा असलहा लहराते हुए वीडियो सामने आया है।"

}
```

both documents are linked with **_id** of master document and **master_id**.
I want to join that table and want to add title in detail document.

and after result I want to add query for search the data from merged document.
below is the query for search.

```
$queryString = ".*".$queryString.".*";
$where = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array(
            'title' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
        ),
        array(
            'description' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline for that

1. Use `$lookup` to join the two collections,
2. `$unwind` the resultant array from `$lookup` stage
3. `$match` to do the regex search

If you need to do the `regex` search on `title` of `master` document as well, you can add that to your `$or` query of the `$match` stage, and if you don't want that, don't forget to remove from the $or query (i have added it).

```
$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$lookup' => array(
            'from' => 'masters',
            'localField' => '$master_id',
            'foreignField' => '$_id',
            'as' => 'master'
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$unwind' => Array(
            'path' => '$master',
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
         ) 
    ),
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            '$or' => array(
                array(
                    'title' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                ),
                array(
                    'description' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                ),
                array(
                    'master.title' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex($queryString),
                ),
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            'field_name' => 1
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$limit' => 10
    )
)

$results = $details->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Now, my php is not that great, still i have managed to write the query for you. Please change/modify the code according to your need.

The thing is i gave you the idea on how to acheive this. Hope that helps.

**Edit**

To `sort`, and `limit`, use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sorthttps://) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit) pipeline stages, I have added that in answer.

Dont forget to replace `field_name` with the actual field you want to sort the result with.

Comment: ,this is working fine after changing little code but '$unwind' => 'master is not working and also how to apply limit and sort option also?

Comment: use `'$unwind'=> '$master'`. Also, for sort and limit, you can add pipeline stages as well. I will update the answer

Comment: everything is working fine except unwind is still not working.Please help  array(
        "\$unwind" => "master"
       ),

Comment: ,now error is not throw but result is blank when putting this code.

Comment: It should be `as : 'master'` in `$lookup` stage instead of `as : master` Also use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` with $unwind. I updated the answer. Check that.

Comment: It is working now,thank you so much for quick reply and help.

Comment: Glad i could help you out!

Comment: ,I want to apply where condition in above query like array(
         array(
         'created_on' => $filterDate,
           ),
         ),   but this is not working.Please help

Comment: use `$expr` for that.