# Mongo DB find - SQL Like - wildcard in the middle

Tags: mongodb, sql-like, regexp-like

This question is very similar to [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like), yet I have not been able to use that or the documentation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ to figure out the query that I need.

I need to find documents in a mongo collection which has values of following format in a field:

"key->some_name::details->(value = '{wild_card_value_here}'):sort->by_name"

In SQL this query would look like

```
SELECT * from some_Table where field like 'key->some_name::details->(value = ''%''):sort->by_name'
```

Note that single quote is part of the string

Here's what I tried with mongo:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({"some_field":{$regex:/^key->some_name::details->(value = '.*'):sort->by_name/}})
```

But it returns 0 documents. I also tried this which did not work either:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({"some_field":"key->some_name::details->(value = '/.*/'):sort->by_name"})
```

I'm unsure if the syntax itself is issue or the special characters in the string like `, -> :` etc.

EDIT:
Example document that I want to be found:

```
{
...
"some_field":"key->some_name::details->(value = 'id_1'):sort->by_name"
...
}
```

and

```
{
...
"some_field":"key->some_name::details->(value = 'id_2'):sort->by_name"
...
}
```

Comment: It is advisable to add an example of the document you are expecting to be found. Ideally if it is not a whole but a stripped-down version with only fields sufficient to reproduce your results, in your case it seems to be "some_field". It also won't harm to practise your regex skills in isolation, e.g. on https://regex101.com/. I'd say `(` and `)` are better candidates to the special characters

Comment: @AlexBlex You were right, it was the special characters `( )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a matter of escaping special characters `(` and  `)`, The query that worked is:

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').find({"some_field":{$regex:/^key->some_name::details->\(value = '.*'\):sort->by_name/}})
```