# How to query MongoDB with “like” in codeigniter?

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

I want to query something with SQL's like query:

`SELECT * FROM users  WHERE name LIKE '%m%'`

How to do I achieve the same in MongoDB? I can't find an operation for like in the documentation of codeigniter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MongoDB with "like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 0):

`db.users.find({"name": /m/}))`

Should be everything you need.

Comment: This doesn't look like the CodeIgniter/PHP syntax that the asker was seeking.