# Implementing Like operator using mongotemplate in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, mongotemplate

In our spring Boot application using mongotemplate, I need to write a query to get the results using `LIKE` operator. But in mongotemplate just like in SQL, I don't have a direct query which I can use.

I have tried with some of the options like `Aggregate` and `regex` methods but it didn't work.

In MongoDB tried the same.

```
db.getCollection('Months').find({"name":/Jan/}).
```

So in the `months` `table`, I have to retrieve results that contains 'Jan' letters in the column 'name'. But on running this query suppose I have an entry called 'DecJan' in that Case I am not able to retrieve it.

```
Query constantQuery = new Query();``
constantQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").regex("DecJan", "i"));

List<Months> pp = this.mongoTemplate.find(constantQuery, Months.class);
```

So, the expected is If I have two entries in a table like 'January','DecJan'
And in a query, if I pass 'Jan', I need to retrieve both the results using mongotemplate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 0):

The duplication link updated does not refer to the mongoTemplate instance which is required..

By the way i have used aggregationOperation for the same and got the results.

1. Creating AggregationOperation
2. Build Aggreation Object with the match required.
3. query with Mongotemplate.aggregate(AggregationOperation,Aggreation)

Sample code:
AggregationOperation aggregate = Aggregation.project().and("FirstName").as("name");

```
        AggregationOperation operation = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("name").regex(pattern, "i"));

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(aggregate, operation);
```

Now able to retrieve the results.