# Retrieving data from mongoDB using a field

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query, data-retrieval

I want to retrieve all the datas from my mongo db collection "Assets" whose "chapterName" is equal to the string sent through the url, How to get it?

```
app.get(`/api/assets/get_all/${chapterName}`, (req, res) => {
  Assets.find({}, (err, assets) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
    res.status(200).send(assets);
  });
});
```

Comment: What is your problem *exactly*? Have you tried looking at similar posts in stack overflow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `chapterName` will be in params of request, req. let's say chaptername is present in mongoose schema.

```
app.get('/api/assets/get_all/:chapterName}', (req, res) => {
  Assets.find({ chaptername: req.params.chapterName }, (err, assets) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
    res.status(200).send(assets);
  });
});
```

Comment: @MustaF if it works, don't forget to mark this as answer.

Comment: @MustaF u r supposed to accept the answer if it solves ur purpose. welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: @prisar I think /${chapterName} must be /:chapterName