# Laravel mongodb where array field contains value

Tags: mysql, laravel, mongodb, eloquent, moloquent

I use mongodb and mysql together with Laravel.
Fields table in mysql database can have more options in mysql database.

- fields table in mysql: *id, name*
- options table in mysql: *id, field_id, name*

so in mongodb database I have adverts table and this adverts table have field and field equal to options
something like this for example **{field_id_1: [option_id, option_id]}**. When I use it like this there is no problem when querying the database. It is simple like this **$advert->whereIn('field_id_1', $request->options)**.

but then I decided why not to keep this options as an array in mongodb and without field_id like this **{options: [option_id, option_id, option_id]}**. So there is the question now I somehow want query the database where this options field contains requests value something reverse of **$adverts->whereIn('field', $options)**

I know a way but not sure

```
$adverts->where('options', 'LIKE', '%"'.$option_id.'"%');
```

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3305687/3710490

Comment: @Valijon so it seems regex searching is expensive query so i am gonna have more than 50k records in database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer will work for you :

```
$result = $adverts->where("options", "all", [$option_id])->get();
```

or :

```
$result = $adverts->where("options", "all", "$options_ids")->get();
```

where ***$options_ids*** are an array of options