# how to make a search in node using mongoose based on keywords

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  project_name: String
});

const User = new mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form  action="/" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="txt">
          <button type="submit" name="button" >Search</button>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

i want that if a project name is "machine learning and oops" and i make a search in the search box for "oops", i should get "machine learning and oops" displayed

Comment: use regular expression for search api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex pattern to do `fuzzy` search like this.

```
User.find({project_name : /your-search-keyword-variable-here/})
```