# How to search on mongodb mongoose ObjectId per keyword?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to search on mongodb mongoose _id ObjectId per keyword?

Example in mysql `` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` LIKE '%keyword%' ``

How can i achieve that in mongodb?

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: I've tried {_id: /KEYWORD/} but still not working esp on ObjectId.