# MongoDB: Not getting any result with $regex with $match and $or for multiple column search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using mongodb 4.4 and making aggregate query to find data from the collection.

Here is my code:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [{
                "name": {
                    $regex: /a/,
                    $options: 'i'
                },
                "email": {
                    $regex: /a/,
                    $options: 'i'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
])
```

I want to do query just like SQL `like` on all column of the user collection. I am not getting any result with this.

CASE 1: If I use `/(:?)/` it does return me all the collection and that works fine
CASE 2: If i user `/ad/` it does not return anything even though there is email and name containing `admin` string.

Comment: remove `/`, when you use single/double quotes in `$regex` operator. use `/a/` or `'a'`

Comment: I have edited question. But seems it still abnormal behaviour as well

Comment: can you explain more what is *abnormal behaviour* in terms of error/problem? provide some example document and your expectation from that document.

Comment: @turivishal please check above edited question and cases at the bottom

Comment: it is the correct query and It should return, see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8cebY9M0q1A), probably you are missing something.

Comment: You have user 'ad' as a string which also works for me but regex is not working,

Comment: I want any matched result that contains matched character

Comment: use, `new RegExp('ad', 'i')` for regular expression in js.

Comment: I have done same for dynamic values but that's the thing still not working

Comment: we can't help you without showing your implementation. look at the similar question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MongoDB with "like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: I have checked and followed same as well but it is not working as expected

Comment: Your query looks good, i have provided solution for js regex, and shared a similar question as well, so we can't help you on the base of your statement *is not working as expected*. we don't have any superpower to debug your code in your machine, you need to share more details, implementation in nodejs.

Comment: Plz check answer

Comment: Both are same query, in your question and in your answer, i don't see any problem in $or in your question.

Comment: It is not same check curly brackets inside or array

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the issue after getting too much over the docs.

there is was a slight problem with the syntax of `$or`

what worked for me is something like this:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
                    $or: [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                $regex: /a/,
                                $options: 'i'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "email": {
                                $regex: /a/,
                                $options: 'i'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
    }
])
```