# Like queries in MongoDb Using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to use like queries for search in my app using MongoDb With PHP but I did not get the proper result.

Code:

```
$query = array("first_name" => "/.*a.*/" );
$updateResult = $this->dbCustomer->find($query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer and I try this and it's work perfect :

$query = array(array("first_name" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("$search_text", 'i')))

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$query = array("first_name" => array("$regex" => "/.a./"));
$updateResult = $this->dbCustomer->find($query);
```

[more details, please check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)