# How to search keyword in nodejs MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want keyword search in nodejs with mongodb as DB,
I tried few things but din't work.

```
const response = await db.collection.find({ $text: { $search:  searchstring }});
```

this is working for text search but not for keyword search.

for ex: if I am searching John , it is giving me all doc containing John but if I am searching with jo , it is giving empty result.

Can anyone please suggest how to search with keyword.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like?rq=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MongoDB with "like"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions:

```
const keyword = 'jo';
const r1 = new RegExp(`\\b${keyword}`, 'i'); // 'i' stands for ignore letter case

const response = await db.collection.find({ text: { $regex: r1 } });
```

This code will retrieve all documents, where text starts with 'jo', ignoring the case.

Comment: I tried this but it is giving empty result

Comment: if (searchstring !== undefined) {
        const r1 = new RegExp(`\\b${searchstring}`, 'i'); 
        const response = await db.collection.find({ text: { $regex: r1 } });
       console.log(response);
       return response?response : null;
    }

Comment: @tiya in your code you should use template literals, because you're searching for `searchString`:
`new RegExp(\`\\b${searchstring}\`, 'i');`
it should work as expected